# How do I make a Twilio call hangup if my app doesn't get a valid response from the call recipient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I want the code below to hangup if I don't get a valid response within 5 seconds after the "last chance" message. I've set `:timeout` to 11. The call should end in 10 seconds, (excluding the time to ask the questions). The 1st question is asked and waits 5 seconds before asking the 2nd. I want the call to hangup after the 2nd `g.pause`. I've tried `r.hangup` in the main block and `g.hangup` in the gather block. Neither of those worked for me. How should it be done?

```
def digits
  twiml_response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Gather numDigits: '1', timeout: 11, action: communications_menu_path do |g|
      g.Say "Please press one to continue", voice: 'alice', language: 'an-AU'
      g.Pause length: 5
      g.Say "Last chance. I didn't get any response. Please press one to continue.", voice: 'alice', language: 'an-AU'
      g.Pause length: 5
    end
  end
  render :xml => twiml_response.to_xml
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When your [`<Gather>` times out](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-timeout) it will still make the request to your `action` attribute. However, the `Digits` parameter to that request will be empty.

So, instead of hanging up in this part of the TwiML, during your next TwiML (under `communications_menu_path`) you should check if the `Digits` parameter is present but empty and then hang up. Something like:

```
def communications_menu
  if params["Digits"] && params["Digits"].blank?
    render :xml => Twilio::TwiML::Response.new { |r| r.Hangup }.to_xml 
  else
    # the rest of the TwiML
  end
end
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: That didn't work @philnash, but I do have in working now. What I've discovered is that my 11 second timeout is added to the end of the last pause, so it waits 11 seconds after the last pause before hanging up. I changed that to 1 and it hangs up 6 second after the last question. The other thing is it's not routing to my communications_menu_path before hanging up . It just hangs up. I don't have a problem with that, but it doesn't route as you've stated.

Comment: I should add that I've incorrectly referenced `r.hangup` and `g.hangup` in my question. It should be `r.Hangup` and `g.Hangup` as Phil has done in his answer.

Comment: Bah, my mistake. You're right, you do need to use the correct capitalisation for that. I was hoping to add case insensitivity to my [twiml_template](https://github.com/philnash/twiml_template) library to make that easier. As for the timeout times, the timeout starts at the end of whatever is inside the `<Gather>` so it starts after your 5 second `<Pause>`.